# Trying to get property of non-object - Query return - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm doing a normal consultation, which I have done many times, but it's the first time I see this error.

The queryTransacao->id variable (above) returns 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Foreach & Query - Controller:

```
foreach ($ this-> input-> post ('check') as $ key) {
    $ queryTransacao = $ this-> boletos-> get_TransacaoIdbyCartao ($ key) -> result ();
    $ this-> boletos-> update_transacoes_inclusao_boleto ($ dadosTransacoes, $ queryTransacao-> id);
}
```

By way of knowledge, the model:

```
public function get_TransacaoIdbyCartao ($ numero_cartao = NULL) {
    $ this-> db-> select ('id, valor_transacao, plano_pagamento, created_at');
    $ this-> db-> where ('numero_cartao', $ numero_cartao);
    $ this-> db-> where ('plano_pagamento', '01'); //?
    return $ this-> db-> get ('bc_transacoes');
}
```

I tried `$queryTransacao['id']` but it returns an undefined index.

Comment: Can you var_dump($queryTransacao); ? I guess it's empty.

Comment: Course, @Lirux - here it goes: 
array(7) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#43 (4) { ["id"]=> int(12206) ["valor"]=> string(12) "000000010000" ["plano"]=> string(2) "01" ["dtCriacao"]=> string(19) "May 22 2015 2:08PM" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#44 (4) { ["id"]=> int(12228) ["valor"]=> string(12) "000000005000" ["plano"]=> string(2) "01" ["dtCriacao"]=> string(19) "May 22 2015 3:48PM" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#45 (4) { ["id"]=> int(12398) ["valor"]=> string(12) "000000010000" ["plano"]=> string(2) "01" ["dtCriacao"]=> string(19) "Jun 10 2015 10:39AM" }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Your controller**

```
 foreach ($ this-> input-> post ('check') as $ key) {
    $ queryTransacao = $ this-> boletos-> get_TransacaoIdbyCartao ($ key) -> result ();
    if(count($ queryTransacao)>0)
    {
        foreach($ queryTransacao as $data){
        $ this-> boletos-> update_transacoes_inclusao_boleto ($ dadosTransacoes, $data-> id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Vinie! Thanks in advance for your help.
The 'row_object' resolved the problem, when I call the variable 'queryTransacao-> id' no longer gives the error, but my problem now is that the 'row_object' just returns me a line! I need the 'result' to bring all the results and update all 'ids' within the condition in the database.

Answer (score 0):

use as given bellow.

```
     foreach ($ this-> input-> post ('check') as $ key) {
     $result = $ this-> boletos-> get_TransacaoIdbyCartao ($ key) -> result();
      foreach($result as $queryTransacao ){
     $ this-> boletos-> update_transacoes_inclusao_boleto ($ dadosTransacoes, $queryTransacao-> id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, @shanusingh ! Thank you in advance for your help.
The 'row' resolved the problem, when I call the variable 'queryTransacao-> id' no longer gives the error, but my problem now is that the 'row' just returns me a line! I need the 'result' to bring all the results and update all 'ids' within the condition in the database.